# Как создать проект React на WebStorm?

Tags: reactjs

Изучаю React , скринкаст на http://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/react
в первом же скринкасте у автора "нулевой" проект, где есть папки `src` с файлом `index.js`, "Public".

Я установил модуль "create-react-native-app" через NPM. В WebStorm выбираю `Create new project > React native`. В созданном проекте этих папок нет (src, public).

Как создать начальный проект React правильно ?
 Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Команда для `create-react-native-app`, после того как вы установили пакет `create-react-native-app` глобально:

```
$ npm install -g create-react-native-app

$ create-react-native-app my-app-name
```

[Почитать тут](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app#creating-an-app)

Comment: Точно так и делал. В папке приложения папки .idea, node_modules, файл package.json. Но нет папок "src", "public". Собственно в этом и вопрос. Я думал, WebStorm потом их создает возможно. Или это не совсем болванка с нуля, как говорится в скринкасте..

Comment: @Алекс Надо самому создать эти папки.

Comment: т.е.так и должно быть ? Понял Вас, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Вот официальный гайд по созданию проекта rn в WebStorm: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/12/developing-mobile-apps-with-react-native-in-webstorm/